# Oracle stored procedure performance issue

Tags: oracle, performance, stored-procedures

There are three tables, TA, TB and TC. One row in TA maps to about 10 rows in TB trough columns in two tables. TB has a CLOB column. TC has the same column names and types as TB, but has no primary key, foreign key, or any index. TA has about 1 million rows, TB has 20 million rows, TC is empty.  Not all rows in TB has corresponding rows in TA, only half (10 million) has corresponding rows in TA.

What I need to do is to copy rows in TB that has associated rows in TA to TC.

In stored procedure, I use cursor to loop through TA, for each row in TA, select out associated rows in TB and insert into TC with one statement like

```
insert into TC select * from TB where TB.col = :value
```

`Commit` is issued after each five rows in TA is processed.

The problem is this simple stored procedure runs fast at the beginning, but becomes more and more slower. For first 1000 rows in TA, it need 1.9 seconds,
the second 1000 rows need 14 seconds, the third 1000 rows needs 37 seconds, and become more and more unacceptable.

Comment: You may want to correct that sentence: _TC has the same column names and types as TC_. Why do you need a stored procedure for this task? For performance issues it might even be better to export the data from your initial query and then bulk-load it.

Comment: Consider reducing the number of commits. With commit every five rows in TA you get 2 million commits, causing a lot of log file syncing. Try committing each 100 rows of TA instead.

Comment: I tried to do it with one SQL statement, but the execution of the SQL didn't finish after 5 hours.

Comment: But it will probably be more efficient to do a single select of all the rows in TB matching rows in TA, and then use bulk operations to put the rows to TC, say 1000 rows each bulk.

Comment: @KamilG. Sorry Kamil - I see you already suggested something like that:)

Comment: @roywang please read my comment again. You could do one statement which would only __read__ data. JensKrogsboell, cool - bumping into same ideas ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in pl/sql try something like this:

```
declare
    cursor src is
        select tb.*
        from    tb
        where exists (
            select null
            from   ta
            where <ta's primary key matches tb's primary keys>
            );
  type t_bulk is table of src%rowtype;
  v_bulk t_bulk;
begin
  open src;
  loop
    fetch src bulk collect into v_bulk limit 1000;
    forall i in 1..v_bulk.count
      insert into tc
        values v_bulk(i);
    commit;
    exit when v_bulk.count < 1000;
  end loop;
  close src;
end;
```

I do not have access to Oracle db just now - this just from memory and might have some syntactical errors.

Update: A simple join between TA and TB might be better than using `exists`. As long as `src` produces exactly the rows you want to insert into TC.

Comment: I tried it, the problem is the same, it run fast at the beginning, and quickly became unacceptable slow.

Comment: Hmm - sounds like some sort of resource contention rather than than a problem with your code then. What kind of installation do you have - big/small?